# key is undefined - I can't delete

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to delete the question after the answer.My key is undefined.
Error:
DELETE http://api/Remove/undefined 400 (Bad Request)

```
state={
qBank:[{id=1,question:'dd',answers:['a','b','c','d'],correct:'a'}]
}
```

render:

```
 this.state.qBank.map(
                                ({ question, answers, correct, id }) => (
                                    <QuestionBox key={id} question={question} options={answers} selected={answer => this.computeAnswer(answer, correct)} />
                                )
                            )}
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const QuestionBox = ({ question, options, selected, key }) => {
    const [answer, setAnswer] = useState(options);
    const [alreadyAnswered, setAlreadyAnswered] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div className="questionBox">
            <div className="question">{question}</div>
            {(answer || []).map((text, index) => (
                <button disabled={alreadyAnswered} key={index} className="answerBtn" onClick={() => {
                    if (!alreadyAnswered) {
                        setAnswer([text]);
                        selected(text);
                        setAlreadyAnswered(true);
                        fetch("http:/api/Remove/" + key, {
                            method: 'DELETE',
                            headers: {
                                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                                "Authorization": `bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem("access_token")}`
                            },
                        }).then(() => {
                        }).catch(err => {
                            console.error(err)
                        })
                    }
                }}>{text}</button>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
export default QuestionBox;
```

Comment: If the site says that your post is mostly code, don't just add junk text to fill it; that's not the intent, and it will not pass by the community.

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The `key` in map has a different purpose in React. Its used for render-optimization.

You **CANNOT** pass key as a prop.

use

`<QuestionBox key={id} id={id} question={question} options={answers} selected={answer => this.computeAnswer(answer, correct)} />`

```
    const QuestionBox = ({ question, options, selected, id }) => {
..code
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, I still have undefined  .. https://pastebin.com/Z15ZpMYJ